# WPF: How to have KeyBinding on Window that doesn't get swallowed by textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to rebind the "Up" key for my window to perform a command on my ViewModel.

My window contains 2 controls: ListView, TextBox.

If I do

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command={Binding SomeCommand} />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Everything works correctly. However, if I set it to "Up", or certain other keys, the command does not get executed if the TextBox has focus. This tells me that the TextBox is handling these keys and swallowing the event that triggers the command. Is there any way to prevent that and to allow the window to get them similar to the Preview events (`PreviewKeyUp`) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an application level shortcut, you can use InputManager

```
InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += (sender,args)
{
    var keyboardEvent = args?.StagingItem?.Input as KeyboardEventArgs;

    if(keyboardEvent != null)
    {
        var keyArgs = keyboardEvent.RoutedEvent as KeyEventArgs;

        if(keyArgs != null)
        {
            if(keyArgs.Key == Key.F5)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }         
    }
};
```

I would recommend taking the logic above and incorporating it into a behavior that you can bind/map Keys to Commands.

Comment: So in this setup, I'd manually map the keys and do something like `commands[matchingCommandKey].Execute(parameter)`? I've got something similar to this right now without using the `InputManager`, where I just use the PreviewKeyPress on the window, but the idea was to try to leverage the command framework

Comment: Yes. I was resorting to the InputManager in order to avoid focus/capture issues. It seems to cross-cut the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to prevent that and to allow the window to get them similar to the Preview events (PreviewKeyUp) ?

You could hook up an event handler to the KeyDownEvent using the overload of the AddHandler method that accepts a "handledEventsToo" boolean parameter and invoke your command from this event handler:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
        AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler((ss, ee) => 
        {
            vm.SomeCommand.Execute(null);
        }), true);
    }
}
```

There is no way to do this in pure XAML though but it doesn't really matter as far as the MVVM pattern is concerned as you simply move the invocation of the command from the XAML markup of the view to the code-behind class of the very same view. This doesn't break the MVVM pattern.